# PlayFramework 2.0 Json to List[String] Conversion

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Converting json to oher type should be easy. From the Play! [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json%24):

```
var str = "{\"next_cursor\":0,\"ids\":[123123,345345],\"previous_cursor\":0}"
var fol = Json.parse(str)
var fin = Json.fromJson[List[String]].fromJson(fol)
```

Should work without problem. It compiles fine, but failed with this error:

```
[RuntimeException: List expected]
```

Instead, this works:

```
var str = "{\"next_cursor\":0,\"ids\":[123123,345345],\"previous_cursor\":0}"
var fol = Json.parse(str)
var fin = (fol \ "ids") match {
    case ids: JsArray => ids.value.map(_.toString)
    case _ => JsArray()
}
```

Why? Am I understanding something wrong with the API? I'm trying this in PlayFramework 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parse this as a `List[String]` directly, as it is a list of numbers, not strings.  Your match example works because you map the ids to a string afterwards.  Using your example, you'd write it more like:

```
val str = "{\"next_cursor\":0,\"ids\":[123123,345345],\"previous_cursor\":0}"
val fol = Json.parse(str)
val fin = Json.fromJson[List[Int]](fol \ "ids")
```

To make the syntax slightly easier to read, I'd make use of `JsValue.as[T]`, which is the equivalent of `Json.fromJson[T]`:

```
val fin = (fol \ "ids").as[List[Int]]
```

And if you need the ids to be converted to strings:

```
val fin = (fol \ "ids").as[List[Int]].map(_.toString)
```

Comment: Never thought it's that simple. This works wonderfully thank you very much.